# unable to mount blank-dvdr disk

Tags: mount, dvd

I have inserted a blank disk into my dvd-rw but in ubuntu its showing an error that unable to mount the place is already mounted?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**gnome-fallback-mount-helper** I do not have this in my list of startup applications.

I'd like to know how I can get rid of this notification as well. It serves no purpose to tell me that it failed to mount it twice, because it is already mounted once. I'm not sure what that even means??? The popup is intrusive, and disrupts my activity, especially if I have to swap many blanks. At the very most, this notification should be in the corner like a notify-send message.

Answer (score -2):

VENKI,

I disable gnome-fallback-mount-helper in startup applications and the error message don't appear anymore and now I can burn CD/DVD with Brasero normaly.